# How to implement auto user login using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We are using mvc framework 6, identity framework 3 and EF 7 with sql server. The webapp requires user authentication and authorization. But there's a situation when we want to authenticate/authorize user from query string. I am having problem in creating usermanager/signinmanager.
This is what AccountController looks like for login

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    public AccountController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    public SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager { get; private set; }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid username or password.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

For auto login from URL string, I want to create or instantiate SigninManager object to I so I could use PasswordSignInAysync method. But I am not sure how to do that. This is what I have , but I am not sure about the arguments to pass.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
       //from url
       if(Request != null)
        {
            if(Request.Query["emailId"] != null)
            {

                var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_dbContext);
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
                //var userstore = new IUserStore(ApplicationUser);
                //var user = new UserManager();
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "someone@XXX.com" };

                var signinmanager = new SignInManager<ApplicationUser>(manager,);

                var result =  await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Request.Query["emailId"],
                                        Request.Query["TokenId"], false, shouldLockout: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("MyHome", "People");
                }
                return RedirectToAction("MyHome",  "People");
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Why do you need auto sign in? How would it be used? I'm only asking this because this has design smells.. Why bother with authentication if your not authenticating the resource owner? Also, you really should never pass login creds via query string as the browser will record it via history + it is sent in referral headers. Please read this for further info: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/

Comment: Signing in via GET using query string is a serious security risk unless its done through some temporary single use auth token such as how password resets are handled.

Comment: @Michael,@br4d : it(auto sign in) arose out of a demand from the stake holders themselves. @ br4d2, yes that is exactly I want to implement it. In general we have good security within application. However, there's a requirement from stakeholders that 'potential customers' - customers whose account has already been created in our database - be taken to a certain view page without the need of having them log in manually. Basically, what I've understood is that they don't want to lose a custmr just because he/she couldn't log in.Hence the need of sending a login url in email which will log'em in.

Comment: What parts of the website do they need to access? full? partial? etc.. If it's just partial you could make a custom login that authorises the user and adds a potential customer claim. Then you make an Attribute which denies access to stuff you don't want users getting access to so if they try to get somwhere they aint supposed to then it will stop em. 

If they want full access, well go back to your stakeholders and hand them a noose, tell them to tie it to the roof and hang it aroudn their heads because their basically doing the same through non-restricted access to authorised content

Comment: @MichaelCrook,  partial access. Yes, that's what I am trying to accomplish. So, looking at Account controller, I believe I need SignInManager object in my Home/Index to do that. The constructor of SignInManager requires few arguments; 1) UserManager, 2nd IHttpContextAccessor , that's where I am stuck. I am not sure what to pass for this 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0):

Answer based off of the conversation in comments:
Ok, what I would recommend is that to do this you create a custom login endpoint which accepts a loginid, that way after you've finished showing a client the site, you can revoke that id and stop un-auth access in the future.

I'm sorry but I don't fully remember how you do a custom login endpoint, I know theres somthing about setting User's authorised.

But once you figure out how to Authorize the user, create a new claims on the users identity of potentialClient, from there you can create an action filter and make it so that people who are potentialClients can only access endpoints which have the custom filter which allows potential clients.

If I find out the way you authorise I'll pass it back to you, I'ts not using the sign in manager though if I remember correct, its somthing pretty simple, like setting something to true.. I wish I could remember but it's evading me.

Hope this helps

Comment: well this where I am exactly stuck! I know I will need a UserStore, a UserManager before I can create SignInManager object. The SignInManager class has a construction, public SignInManager(UserManager<TUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor = null, ILoggerFactory logger = null) . This is where I am having trouble i.e what arguments to pass on  as IHttpContextAccessor etc.